# Does hadoop itself contains fault-tolerance failover functionality?

Tags: hadoop, high-availability, failover, fault

I just installed new version of hadoop2, I wish to know if I config a hadoop cluster and it's brought up, how can I know if data transmission is failed, and there's a need for failover?

Do I have to install other components like zookeeper to track/enable any HA events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High Availability is not enabled by default. I would highly encourage you to read the Hadoop documentation from Apache. (http://hadoop.apache.org/) It will give an overview of the architecture and services that run on a Hadoop cluster.

Zookeeper is required for many Hadoop services to coordinate their actions across the entire Hadoop cluster, regardless of the cluster being HA or not. More information can be found in the Apache Zookeeper documentation (http://zookeeper.apache.org/).